# Efficient Query Generation for Permutations of Tags

Tags: sql, performance, algorithm

Here's a simplified version of a problem I'm encountering at work. The details have been changed and more generalized so I can explain it easier.

Let's say you have a blog engine that allows blog posts to be assigned tags when they're created. So I could write a post titled "My Vacation in Italy", and I decide to add the following tags to it: `has-photos`, `vacation`, `family`. As part of my blog engine, I can create custom actions based on groups of tags. So I decided before writing it that any post with the tags `has-photos` and `family` will be automatically shared on Facebook. When that post is created for the first time, I have to then automatically cross-reference all of its tags with all actions that can be performed on combinations of those tags.

When the "My Vacation in Italy" post is saved, I then need to look-up all actions for the following groups of tags:

- `has-photos`
- `vacation`
- `family`
- `has-photos` & `vacation`
- `has-photos` & `family`
- `vacation` & `family`
- `has-photos` & `vacation` & `family`

Generating that query is trivial, I just get all the permutations of any length from the original tag set of the post. It comes out to being `2^N - 1` possibilities of tag combinations.

The problem I'm running into arises when you put this up against large datasets. What we're dealing with are the following:

- 10,000+ "posts" arriving daily
- 20+ "tags" per "post"
- 1,000s of "actions" existing already when blog posts arrive, with varying #s of tags they're triggered on

When a post arrives with 20 tags, that comes out to a little over a million permutations I'd be generating a query for. Even if my database allowed me to send query strings to it that large (hint: it doesn't), it'd still take forever to run.

Is there a clever solution to this I'm not thinking of? Right now as I see it, I'm left with one possibility:

#### Actions use OR instead of AND

I could change it so that when you create a pre-defined action, the tags it acts on are implicitly OR'ed instead of AND'ed. Then the tag combinations drops from `2^N - 1` to just `N`. Unfortunately this would severely limit the usefulness of the "tag action" feature.

Edit: I'm not necessarily looking for an answer in SQL. Just a different approach to solving this problem, even if it's just a high level description.

Comment: Can't you do this when you create the post, when presumably you have the tags to start off with and so don't need to hit the database? Fire off a (presumably async) action to do whatever is needed. (If this doesn't solve your actual problem, then you may have oversimplified; or I may have misunderstood :-)

Comment: @JamesAylett Yes, forcing the user to explicitly declare actions every time they create a post would "solve" this. Sadly that's not an option with my real scenario. What I call "blog posts" in the question are actually generated from other software, and that software has no concept of what actions may or may not be created or present.

Comment: No, don't get them to declare the actions. You said that the tags select which actions happen, so presumably the tags are generated by the software as it stands.

Comment: I know you said you are looking for a high-level suggestion, but can you also specify how your db schema for an action rule looks like?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem? I'm curious how you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn this problem around: For all possible matches which you have actions for (in your example only `has-photos and family`) calculate if the post matches this action. If you only have a few actions with only a few triggers, this will be fast.

Comment: Thanks, I could definitely see this working. Even though the # of actions we have is large (1000+), there would be much less for a given set of tags. Looping over those would be much faster than generating some enormous query.

Comment: Improvement: You can index your actions. For each tag in each action put that action in a map/dictionary keyed by the tag. Then, you only need to look at those actions which you can find by probing the dictionary with the actual tags of the post. That will reduce your search space a lot, although it is not perfect. You can push this to become more clever by indexing pairs of tags to reduce the search space even further.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the sort of thing that rules engine algorithms like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm do. I guess a first step towards this would be to keep a list of the 1000s of actions in memory, and to have something faster than SQL check through them when a new post is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `GROUP BY`,`COUNT` and `HAVING`: store the number of tags per actions at the action's row, and now you can easily get the matching actions' ids:

Database structure:

```
tag
  id
  name

action
  id
  tag_count
  // = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM action_tag WHERE action_tag.action_id=action.id

action_tag
  action_id
  tag_id
```

Example rows:

```
tag
id name
1  has-photos
2  vacation
3  family

action
id tag_count
1  1
2  3

action_tag
action_id tag_id
1         3
2         1
2         2
2         3
```

The select:

```
SELECT     action.id
FROM       action
INNER JOIN tag         ON tag.name IN (<tag_1>,<tag_2>,....)
INNER JOIN action_tag  ON action_tag.action_id = action.id
                      AND action_tag.tag_id = tag.id
GROUP BY action.id
HAVING COUNT( action_tag ) = action.tag_count
```